# Flutter : How to show Firebase Auth exceptions in the consle?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

so my problem is after catching the error it's taking me to another file called(message_error.dart) and showing me the error there , so i want to be able to write the error in the consle  instade of see it on that file

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the VScode i redownload it and it works now